# Create document from dotx template with Apache POI HWPF

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I would like to crate new document from existing `dotx` template.

I tried couple of ways listed here - [How can I use predefined formats in DOCX with POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643822/how-can-i-use-predefined-formats-in-docx-with-poi) But none of them work.

Setting styles has no affect whatsoever.

```
XWPFDocument template = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("template.dotx")));       

XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();      
XWPFStyles newStyles = doc.createStyles();
newStyles.setStyles(template.getStyle());

XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
para.setStyle("Heading1");

XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
run.setText("Heading 1");
```

Creating document directly from template corrupts newly created document and MS Word fails to open it. Complaining that there is a problem inside the document, without any specific details.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("template.docx");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to accomplish this is to use the "replaceContentType" method of the OPCPackage.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(src.getAbsolutePath());
pkg.replaceContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml",
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml");
pkg.save(dest);
```

In the above code both "src" and "dest" are java "File" objects.

Once you have saved the file you can then open it up as an XWPFDocument and perform whatever type of additional manipulation you desire.