# Unable to apply table styles in MS word using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am developing an application where i am using POI library to generate .docx files.
By using `XWPFTable` I am unable to apply table styles. can any one worked on this part? There are no examples and not good documentation out there.

Here is my snippet.

```
        int nRows = 14;
        int nCols = 6;
        XWPFTable t1 = doc.createTable(nRows, nCols);
        t1.setStyleID("Table Grid");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get answer? on how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. I added a template with few styles in it. It worked.

[This question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643822/how-can-i-use-predefined-formats-in-docx-with-poi)

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled on this issue. I have created an empty docx file with all my juicy style available (Heading 1, 2, etc...). I create a XWPFDocument

```
    try {
        InputStream resourceAsStream =  new FileInputStream("protocol_empty.docx");       
        document = new XWPFDocument(resourceAsStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then add my paragraph my setting the style ....setStyle("Heading 1");

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble identifying the styleId to use. If you make a template and add the table with the style in, export it as a Word XML file then you can look up styleId. So "Light List" for me was actually "LightList" (w:style w:type="table" w:styleId="LightList").