# How to set heading style for a paragraph in a docx file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, file, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to create a docx file with poi but I cannot set heading style for a paragraph.

```java
    XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); 
    
    //Write the Document in file system
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/2/Desktop/RequirementModelDocument.docx"));

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();


    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    paragraph.setStyle("Heading1");
    
    run.setText(reqLevel.getName());
    run.setBold(true);
    run.setFontFamily("Calibri Light (Headings)");
```

Its like ignores the `paragraph.setStyle("Heading1");` line. I've looked at the apache's examples but I could not see any example about this issue.

Comment: Does your document have a `Heading1` style in it?

Comment: File is created by XWPFDocument. Actually I do not know wheter the doc has style or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution in the link below. Sorry for the duplication.

[How can I use predefined formats in DOCX with POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643822/how-can-i-use-predefined-formats-in-docx-with-poi)

But, If you have any other solution without using a template file, please let me know :)

Answer (score 6):

If you start a new document, there are no styles defined. Either start from an existing template and copy the styles, or create your own (like I did, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864752/461499 )

See here:

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();

    String heading1 = "My Heading 1";
    String heading2 = "My Heading 2";
    String heading3 = "My Heading 3";   
    String heading4 = "My Heading 4";
    addCustomHeadingStyle(document, styles, heading1, 1, 36, "4288BC");
    addCustomHeadingStyle(document, styles, heading2, 2, 28, "4288BC");
    addCustomHeadingStyle(document, styles, heading3, 3, 24, "4288BC");
    addCustomHeadingStyle(document, styles, heading4, 4, 20, "000000");

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setStyle(heading1);
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Nice header!");
```

And

```
private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFDocument docxDocument, XWPFStyles styles, String strStyleId, int headingLevel, int pointSize, String hexColor) {

    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);
    

    CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();
    styleName.setVal(strStyleId);
    ctStyle.setName(styleName);

    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));

    // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);

    CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);

    // style shows up in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);

    // style defines a heading of the given level
    CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();
    ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);
    ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);

    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);

    CTHpsMeasure size = CTHpsMeasure.Factory.newInstance();
    size.setVal(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(pointSize)));
    CTHpsMeasure size2 = CTHpsMeasure.Factory.newInstance();
    size2.setVal(new BigInteger("24"));
    
    CTFonts fonts = CTFonts.Factory.newInstance();
    fonts.setAscii("Loma" );

    CTRPr rpr = CTRPr.Factory.newInstance();
    rpr.setRFonts(fonts);
    rpr.setSz(size);
    rpr.setSzCs(size2);

    CTColor color=CTColor.Factory.newInstance();
    color.setVal(hexToBytes(hexColor));
    rpr.setColor(color);
    style.getCTStyle().setRPr(rpr);
    // is a null op if already defined

    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);

}

public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hexString) {
     HexBinaryAdapter adapter = new HexBinaryAdapter();
     byte[] bytes = adapter.unmarshal(hexString);
     return bytes;
}
```

Comment: what is fonts.setAscii and fonts.setHAnsi? what is diffrence between them? where do you write fontFamily or fontName? @RobAu

Comment: You set the font for the set of characters. Ascii or High Ansi. You can read more here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeinteroperability/2013/04/22/office-open-xml-themes-schemes-and-fonts/

Comment: So here it is font  'Loma' for the ascii characters.

Comment: How can we set alignment for style? How does style become Bold?@RobAu