# Apache POI Word using custom styles for titles

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I am trying to create heading titles in a word (.docx) document, using apache-poi.

I have a template which contains only custom styles AND example of heading titles using the custom styles.

```
XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("template.docx"));
```

My custom style is called "CUSTOM_YNP" (I created it directly in Word), but when I use the line below, it returns false

```
document.getStyles().styleExist("CUSTOM_YNP")
```

And, of course, when I try to use this style, it doesn't work, actually it print my string in "Normal" style

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph=document.createParagraph();
paragraph.setStyle("CUSTOM_YNP");
XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("TEST");
```

Just for the record, my "save document" line :

```
document.write(new FileOutputStream("myDoc.docx"));
```

I have read this question, but can't actually find a solution to my problem... [How can I use predefined formats in DOCX with POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643822/how-can-i-use-predefined-formats-in-docx-with-poi)

EDIT : It works if I create my own style using Apache-POI.... Still I woudl really like to use existing styles from the word document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `*.docx` is a `ZIP` archive. You can unzip it and look into the `/word/styles.xml`. There you will see that the `w:styleId="CUSTOMYNP"` without the underscore. The name is "CUSTOM_YNP" `<w:name w:val="CUSTOM_YNP"/>`. So:

```
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("template.docx"));

  System.out.println(document.getStyles().styleExist("CUSTOMYNP"));
  System.out.println(document.getStyles().getStyle("CUSTOMYNP").getName());

  XWPFParagraph paragraph=document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setStyle("CUSTOMYNP");
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("TEST");

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("myDoc.docx"));
  document.close();
```

Comment: That's it ! The "real" style name can be different from the "displayed" style name in Word. Also, I've noticed that I didn't need to have my style already used in my template, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you first create the Style and add it to your document:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();

String heading1 = "My Heading 1";
addCustomHeadingStyle(document, styles, heading1, 1, 36, "4288BC");

XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
paragraph.setStyle(heading1);
```

With the addCustomHeadingStyle being:

```
private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFDocument docxDocument, XWPFStyles styles, String strStyleId, int headingLevel, int pointSize, String hexColor) {

    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ...
    //create your style
    ...
    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);

    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to use an EXISTING style which is already in my template.docx... Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the docx file contains the Style? Does the docx file contain any text? _It appears word discards unused styles from the template document. You'll need to have existing text in the document using those Styles_.