# Apply style and numbering to word document with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am using Apache POI to edit the content of a docx file. I also need to apply a specific style to said docx. The style I need to apply is in a dotx file.
In this question [How can I use predefined formats in DOCX with POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643822/how-can-i-use-predefined-formats-in-docx-with-poi/13642129#13642129) I have found the following solution:

```
XWPFDocument template = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("Template.dotx")));       

XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();      
// let's copy styles from template to new doc
doc.createStyles().setStyles(template.getStyle());
```

It was working very well until something changed recently. After some research, I have found that the problem comes from the numbering.xml inside docx file.
From what I understand, numbering.xml and styles.xml are linked.
So setting style to `XWPFDocument` is good, but I also need to set numbering.

I have found equivalent method to `createStyles().setStyles(xxx)`:
`createNumbering().setNumbering(yyy)`.

`setNumbering` expects a parameter of type `CTNumbering` (just like `setStyles` expects a parameter of `CTSyles`).
While a document has a method `getStyles()` returning a `CTSyles`, it does not have a method returning a `CTNumbering`. It does however have a `getNumbering` method returning a `XWPFNumbering` (again, juste like it has a `getStyle()` -without a s- returning a `XWPFStyles`).

I looked into the `getStyles()` -with a s- method and I have been able to create an equivalent one returning a `CTNumbering`.

My question is: is there a simpler way to apply the numbering of a document to another ?